# Wordpress insertar blob mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, archivo, insert, blob

Estoy intentando guardar un archivo en un campo de BBDD.
Llevo buscando varios días y no encuentro una solución que me permita insertarlo desde wordpress (php) + javascript + mysql. He conseguido insertar datos en una tabla de tipo numérico o texto sin problema, pero cuando intento meter un campo blob no consigo que funcione.

He creado una tabla en MySql que se llama clientes y tiene los siguientes campos:

```
CREATE TABLE `clientes` (
    `num_cliente` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `documento` LONGBLOB NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (`num_cliente`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
;
```

En html tengo un formulario con los dos campos y un botón:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="lista_clientes" name="lista_clientes">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-style:none;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="border-style:none;">
                <label for="num_cliente">Número de cliente</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="num_cliente" name="num_cliente">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="border-style:none;">
                <label id="lbl_documento" for="documento">Documento</label>
                <input type="file" id="documento" name="documento">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center;border-style:none;">
                <button id="btn_insertar_cliente" onclick="enviar_param_clientes(document.lista_clientes.num_cliente.value,document.lista_clientes.documento.value">INSERTAR</button>
            </td>
        <tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

En Javascript tengo la función que trae los parámetros y la función onclick del botón:

```
function enviar_param_clientes(par_num_cliente, par_documento){
    var_num_cliente = par_num_cliente;
    var_documento = par_documento;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// Botón insertar cliente
$("#btn_insertar_cliente").on("click", function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : dcms_vars.ajaxurl,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            action : 'insertar_cliente',
            arg_num_cliente: var_num_cliente,
            arg_documento: var_documento
        },
        success: function(){
            alert('Se ha insertado correctamente.');
        }
    });
});
}
```

Y en el fichero functions.php tengo la carga inicial del js y la función de inserción a bbdd:

```
<?php

function carga_inicial(){
    wp_register_script('dcms_miscript',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'javascript.js', array('jquery'), '1', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('dcms_miscript');
    wp_localize_script('dcms_miscript','dcms_vars',['ajaxurl'=>admin_url('admin-ajax.php')]);
    wp_enqueue_style('custom-style',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'css.css', array(), wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'carga_inicial');

function insertar_cliente()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $arg_num_cliente = $_POST['arg_num_cliente'];
    $arg_documento = $_POST['arg_documento'];
    $wpdb->insert('clientes', array('num_cliente' => $arg_num_cliente, 'documento' => $arg_documento ) );

    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_insertar_cliente','insertar_cliente');
```

Cuando inserto un registro, en el campo documento me guarda la ruta así: "C:\fakepath\prueba.pdf" pero no me guarda el documento en cuestión.

He leído que hay dos formas de hacer esto, la fácil (subir el fichero a una carpeta y guardarte la ruta) o la compleja (subirlo a bbdd que es la que necesito). Pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo directamente a bbdd.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme por favor?

Gracias,
Gaucho